# How to contain imported css within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm loading emails (via gmail's api) using Angular:

```
<div class="email-body">
  <div compile-html data-html="thread.message.body"></div>
</div>
```

When I do so, the loaded emails bring with them css styling that affect the css of the whole site.

For example, my css:

```
.container {
  width: 80%;
}
```

But an email (once loaded) brings the following css:

```
.container {
  width: 20% !important;
}
```

The css for .container gets overridden by the newly loaded css.  Is there a way I could contain the imported css within a div (`email-body`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Div with external stylesheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356939/div-with-external-stylesheet)

Comment: Do you know of an alternative way to do it without using an iframe?

Comment: Could you not just remove all <style> nodes when loading the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could might not be the fastest way, but gets the job done without iframes (using javascript and jquery):

```
  $('.email-body').find('*').each(function () {
    if ($(this).css("width")) {
      var setWidth = $(this).css("width");

      //clearing width value
      setWidth = setWidth.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

      $(this).css("width", NEW WIDTH VALUE HERE);
    }
  })
```

If you are using Angular, you might want to wrap this in a $timeout.